# Python Pandas Date filtering

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file having Start date and end date column which I want to filter

Everything runs fine with the below mentioned code but one problem still exists

Problem - When filter the data it gives me results exceeding the end date .e.g. - if my end date is 5/29/2019 it gives me results till 5/31/2019. I just want the results to remain within or less than the end date.

How can this be achieved?

Code used

```py
df['QC START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QC START DATE'])
df = df[(((df['QC START DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) &
 (df['QC START DATE'] <= endateEn.get())) | 
((df['QC END DATE'] >= startdateEn.get()) &
 (df['QC END DATE'] <= endateEn.get())))]
```

Comment: What is `print (df['QC START DATE'].dtype)` ?

Comment: because if not datetimes, first necessary converting - `df['QC START DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df['QC START DATE'])`

Comment: Yes it's converted and everything works well except the problem mentioned above

Comment: If I use the Start Date as  1/1/2019 and End Date as 1/7/2019 , the filtering should be done as I want those entries having the end date till 1/7/2019 even if the start date is not within 1/1/2019

Answer (score 0):

> If I use the Start Date as 1/1/2019 and End Date as 1/7/2019 , the filtering should be done as I want those entries having the end date till 1/7/2019 even if the start date is not within 1/1/2019

So... if I'm understanding correctly, all you want us to do is filter the end date? If the start date can be outside the range, then you aren't filtering it. I'm assuming what you want is the end date between two date ranges: `start < end dates < end`

Assuming your data is in datetime format:

```py
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime
start_date = datetime_object = datetime.strptime('6/2/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
end_date = datetime_object = datetime.strptime('12/2/2018', '%m/%d/%Y')
sub_set = dates[dates["end_date"].apply(lambda x: start_date <= datetime.strptime(x, '%m/%d/%Y') <= end_date)]
display (subset)

output:

dates
0   8/3/2018
1   9/13/2018
3   7/10/2018
4   10/20/2018
6   8/13/2018
7   10/8/2018
9   10/22/2018
12  8/30/2018
13  11/18/2018
14  7/3/2018
15  7/26/2018
19  10/20/2018
23  9/3/2018
24  10/19/2018
27  8/31/2018
30  9/27/2018
34  8/3/2018
36  8/26/2018
40  7/11/2018
41  9/6/2018
42  9/16/2018
48  8/22/2018
```

Comment: ```If the start date can be outside the range, then you aren't filtering it``` - No, If a particular entry has a start date outside the range but has the end date within the range then I want that entry to appear as the end date is in the range.